# Open downloads in FileOpenPicker on Window Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, filepicker, known-folders

I am trying to set suggested location for FileOpenPicker. Here is how i did this:

```
var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
```

It working fine on WinRT and i getting directly `Downloads` folder. But on windows phone it's don't working. Instead of getting `Downloads` its showing list of default folders to pick.
After some time fixing this problem i found, if i'll set `FileTypeFilter` like that:

```
var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
```

it will open `PictureLibrary`. Funny thing, it don't metter what i setting to `SuggestedStartLocation`, it will be always `PictureLibrary`.
Has someone faced this problem before? I will be appreciate for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

`SuggestedStartLocation` is just that -- a suggestion. You can't use it to force the file picker to open a certain location. For example if the user navigated to another location previously and opened a file there, the file picker will start there. A little problematic for testing, but actually very intuitive for the user.